# Find the value of this logarithmic expression involving fifth root of unity.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, absolute-value, roots-of-unity

> Let $\alpha$ be the fifth root of unity. We then want to evaluate the
>   expression $$\log |1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 - 1/\alpha |$$

Thanks in anticipation for your help in solving this!

Comment: Please note that Homework questions are supposed to supposed to show more effort. For more details, please see the [Homework Policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3=\frac{1-\alpha^4}{1-\alpha}=\frac{1-\frac1\alpha}{1-\alpha}\text{ as }\alpha^5=1$$

$$\implies 1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3=\frac{1-\alpha}{-\alpha(1-\alpha)}=-\frac1\alpha\text{ as }\alpha\ne1$$

Comment: This would leave us with $log |-2/\alpha|$. How to proceed from there?

Comment: @user87049, have you meant modulus? If yes, $|-\frac2\alpha|=?$

Comment: Yes, that's a modulus. How do we further simplify the expression? The final answer is an integer.

Comment: @user87049, As $\alpha^5=1, |\alpha^5|=1\implies |\alpha|=1$  Or as $1=\cos2k\pi+i\sin2k\pi$ where $k$ is any integer, using this(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula#Applications) $\alpha=\cos\frac{2k\pi}5+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}5$ where $k=0,1,2,3,4$ $\implies |\alpha|=1$. How can be the answer an integer?

Comment: Thanks so much! This suggests that the answer should be 1/2, right? The source of this question has cited an answer of -1 though.

Comment: @\user87049 The answer is $\log2$ and it is not an integer.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Yes, thanks! I forgot to mention that the base of the logarithm is 4. Hence the answer should be 1/2.

Comment: @user87049 then it is ok.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay, $\frac12$ is not an integer, either

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes, I forgot to mention that my "ok" referred to the 1/2 :-).

Comment: @user87049: Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted and upvote it since it seems that this will suffice.